# How to Rebuild ListViewBuilder after Firebase Cloud Messaging Instance received?

Tags: json, flutter, listview, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've got a listview created from an HTTP query.
I'm trying to append any new FCM notifications to the top of the list;
But although the length of the list does appear to increase with each new notification the listview won't rebuild and the new entry doesn't appear at the top in my listview.

Here's the function;

```
@override
  void onNotify(RemoteMessage notification) {
    _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(notification);
    setState(() {
      _notification = notification;
      Map<String, dynamic> notifData = _notification.data;
      fcmcrafts.insert(0, FCMContent.fromJson(notifData));
      print(widget.fcmcrafts.length);
    });
  }
```

The printout for `print(widget.fcmcrafts.length);` shows the list is updating as it should with each notification increasing the length of the list.

But how can I get the listview to rebuild upon each new inserted notification?

Here's the listview builder;

```
ListView.builder(
           itemCount: widget.fcmcrafts.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, int currentIndex) {
          return createViewItem(widget.fcmcrafts[currentIndex], context,
              currentIndex, widget.fcmcrafts.length);
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what I did but suddenly it's working with the code above. I'll leave it as an answer in case somebody wants to know how to add FCM messages to a mapped list.